# Title of short story about returning astronauts who develop a "long gaze" or "long stare" and cannot relate to earthly life anymore?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Astronauts returning to Earth develop a "long gaze" or "long stare" that is inexplicable to doctors. They keep staring into the distance. Anyone know the title? I suspected it to be written by Bradbury or Ballard but cannot find it.

Potentially read around 30 years ago, the astronauts had returned from an interstellar trip and had begun to develop the symptoms over time.

This question might relate to this one:

[Short story about astronauts returning from space and going crazy on earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/229344/short-story-about-astronauts-returning-from-space-and-going-crazy-on-earth)

Comment: Firstly, nothing about this story is science fiction, at the moment. Astronauts are science fact and there's no reason a current astronaut couldn't develop a "long stare". Could you provide any details that sets this story apart as science fiction? Secondly, can you provide any more details about the story, such as when you read it, or any other details in the story such as why the astronauts developed the long stare, how long was their mission, where did they go?

Comment: I think I read it about 30 years ago, hence a near complete lack of details. The story impressed me because of it's melancholy tone: the astronauts - interstellar I think, so sf for the moment - upon return seemed normal but over time they started to stare into the distance, possibly with bloodshot eyes although I am not sure about that either. I think the reason why they turned into themselves was explored but not explained in the story: spacetravel makes you strangely and alarmingly 'other', that's what remains of the story in mij recollection. It was more philosophical than hard science.

Comment: @user14111 as much as I do to believe it's over 54 years old? I also don't see any mention of the moon, it just says "return to Earth" which would bring it to 61 years based on the first human space flight in 1962. Not sure why you've chosen to be so confrontational but I hope that answers your question :)

Comment: @Robert these are very useful additions, I've added them to the post, should you choose to add anything else feel free to [edit] it in.

Comment: @edlothiad I think it's pretty unlikely a story about astronauts having been affected by something in space is going to fall under any genre other than science fiction. It's a reach. Also, the related question linked was accepted by this site and has no more mention in it of other SF tropes than this one does.

Comment: The OP says interstellar trip, so surely that's SF

Comment: In the Ballard story *The Message from Mars* the crew of a mission to Mars refuse to leave the ship after returning to Earth because they have become disinterested in everyday life. However the story doesn't mention them staring. The nearest we get to this is when the story ends: "*Most mysteriously, across their eyes moved the continuous play of a keen and amused intelligence.*"

Comment: @Robert   In history, astronauts are space travelers sent into space by NASA & other US agencies. The word was used to describe space travelers for decades before being officially adopted by the US government.   Are the characters called astronauts in the story or is that merely the word you chose for the question?  If they are called astronauts in the story and are not sent on a US government mission that detail alone would be sufficient to make the story science fiction.

Comment: Based on the discussion above would a question about a film such as Gravity be considered on topic? I shall have a look on meta and if I can't find anything I might pose it there.

Comment: @WiggotheWookie there are several questions about that film here already. It even has a tag [gravity-movie] That doesn't mean *any* question about it is on topic, of course.

Comment: @OrganicMarble But why? It's setting is current (actually historic as it has a shuttle) and I don't remember any speculative technology elements. I love the film and gut response says it's sci fi. But when I think about why... I'm off the the SF and F tour, and then probably Meta.

Comment: @WiggotheWookie - Gravity is science fiction because it's based on a speculative set of events involving a fictional anti-satellite weapon that causes a Kessler Syndrome cascade

Answer (score 8):

This is a long shot because there is no interstellar travel, it's about astronauts exploring the moon:

["The Far Look"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55784), a novelette by [Theodore L. Thomas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodore_L._Thomas), which was also the answer to [this old question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179493/short-story-a-base-on-the-moon-and-the-perceived-problems-occupants-believe-the); first published in [*Astounding Science Fiction*, August 1956](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57420), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v57n06_1956-08_Gorgon776/page/n115/mode/2up); you may have read in in one of [these compilations](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?55784).

In this excerpt, two astronauts have just returned from the moon:

> But the cameras did not focus on the general appearance or action of the men. The zoom lenses went to work and a close-up of the faces of the two men side by side flashed across the country.
>
> The faces even at first glance seemed different. And as the cameras lingered, it became apparent that there was something quite extraordinary there. These were men, but the eyes were different. There was an expression not found in human eyes. It was a level-eyed expression, undeviating. It was a penetrating, probing expression, yet one laden with compassion. There was a look in those eyes of things seen from
> deep inside, of things seen beyond the range of normal vision. It was a far look, a compelling look, a powerful look set in the eyes of normal men. And even when those eyes were closed, there was something different. A network of tiny creases laced out from both corners of each eye. The crinkled appearance of the eyes made each man appear older than he was, older and strangely wizened.

Comment: It took me two days to read through that story. It's certainly about The Far Look, which is odd, since it never really goes into it. People on earth look for it, see it, say "Yup, a few more of them and they can run things" -- and then it goes into the story of the two men.

Comment: And McIntosh calls Fowler "Walt". . . McIntosh says "What is it, Walt?" and then Fowler screams for Walt to answer. . . McIntosh says "Something moved, Don". . .  and there are only two of them --  talking to each other.

I will watch for stories about returning from interstellar trips.

Answer (score 5):

William Gibson's 1981 short story "[Hinterlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinterlands_(short_story))" which was originally published in *Omni*, and subsequently collected in the anthology [*Burning Chrome*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burning_Chrome_(short_story_collection)) is about astronauts who are arbitrarily permitted (or not) by some alien agency to travel solo through a poorly understood interstellar transit point. Those who return bring fabulous wealth in terms of advanced technology, evidence of exobiology, etc., but who are uniformly profoundly traumatized by the experience, often reduced to staring catatonically. The tale is told from the perspective of a prospective astronaut who was not chosen to travel, and whose new life is to try to protect astronauts who return alive from their commonly self-destructive impulses.

Comment: And do they develop a long gaze or long stare?

Comment: @Valorum - "staring catatonically" sounds close enough

Comment: @Basya - I don't think they're the same, and OP is pretty insistent that the distance of the stare is a component of the description;

Comment: @Valorum We disagree, and Basya lands precisely on my thinking.